# Is there any way to stop triggering the deep watch when I remove or splice an element on an array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem in Vue.js 2.0. I noticed that when I removed an element from an array. The deep watch on the component will be triggered and will be resetting the value of each component that are after the removed element index.

I have a component of Filter Modal. This filter modal component has options of different kind of filters. It has a button of delete that will trigger the deleteFilter(index);

```
function deleteFilter(index) {
    this.filters.splice(index, 1);
}
```

**this.filters** is an array variable that holds the selected filters.

And I have a component inside the filter modal, which is filter selected.

In filter modal, there is an filter selected and has a v-for of this.filters

```
<filterselected>
    v-for='selectedFilter, index) in filters'
    :index='index'
</filterselected>
```

In filter selected, there are deep watch for its data(). This deep watch for filter selected component, mainly use to set the this.inputValue with the passing data from watch event. And will be sending back or will be emitting the value to the parent component.

**MAIN PROBLEM**

So the main problem here is when I removed an element from array (this.filters), the deep watch event will be triggered and set the this.inputValue with null value or undefined or idontknow, then will be emitting to the parent component. So when a null/undefined or idontknow value will be passing and if the type of filter is date picker filter then the value of datepicker will be 'NAN' because datepicker cannot hold a value like that.

So how to prevent this happening?

> UPDATE:

Sample watch event

```
Watch: {
    date: {
        handler(val){
           this.inputValue = val;
        },
        deep: true
    },
    inputValue: function(){
        this.$emit('changeinput', { value: this.inputValue }
    }
}
```

I noticed that when I removed an element from the array, the deep watch event (date) will be triggered and will be getting a null/unidentified value that will be set this value to this.inputValue.

Then once the value is set to this.inputValue, there's a watch event also and will be triggered after and this watch will emit the value to the parent component

Comment: Can tou try to reproduce this behavior writing a running example here? Or, if you can't can you share a little bit more of your code so that we can have a better understanding?

Comment: Hi @BernardoDuarte I edited my post. You may check the additional info there. Thank you

Comment: It looks like it's just a problem with loop keys. If you put a suitable `key` attribute on the `<filterselected>` it should stop all the components being shuffled along when one is removed. You need to choose a `key` carefully though, using `index` won't help, it must be something that uniquely identifies the filter.